# Google plus button don´t register +1

Tags: google-plus-one

Have a really weird problem on a site with the Google +1 button and am not so sure it's a local thing.

Website is casinoplacard.com and it have been using the +1 from start and all was working fine but a some moment i did stop to show the amount of +1's

- The code shall be correct
- It's possible to click it, It's show "1" and you can share content
- Analytics to pick up some of the clicks

And the thing that does the thing more weird is that if i put my url in the button on some other page or using http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html  the same problem does exist.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

When I enter the URL http://www.casinoplacard.com/ into http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html, it's telling me it has 8 likes.  When I navigate to http://www.casinoplacard.com/, I see 8 likes.

Maybe you have a hosts file entry on your local box pointing at a development version of the site?

Comment: After alot of filtering out possible causes i was 100% sure that the problem wasn't local. 

Did write a post about it on the Google plus developer forum and within 48 hours it was working much better, still some pages where it get's stuck but overall it's working.